# Duplicate columns get created while clicking "Edit" in asp:GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have `asp:GridView` where I am using `AutoGenerateEditButton="True"` property to edit the grid row. Now the issue is whenever I click `Edit` button, the columns are populating again. For example If there 4 columns and if I click `Edit` than same 4 columns will reappear.

.ASPX Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEmpDetail" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            OnRowEditing="grdEmpDetail_RowEditing"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="grdEmpDetail_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdated="grdEmpDetail_RowUpdated" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind: To Dynamically bind data on grid

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject objBL = new WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject();
    this.grdEmpDetail.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = objBL.OrderDetail();
        foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ToString() == "ID" || col.ToString() == "First Name" || col.ToString() == "Last Name" || col.ToString() == "Business Phone" || col.ToString() == "Job Title")
            {
                BoundField objBoundField = new BoundField();
                objBoundField.DataField = col.ToString();
                objBoundField.HeaderText = col.ToString();
                this.grdEmpDetail.Columns.Add(objBoundField);
            }
        }
        this.grdEmpDetail.DataSource = dt;
        this.grdEmpDetail.DataBind();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Handle Edit Mode:

```
protected void grdEmpDetail_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.grdEmpDetail.DataBind();
    }

protected void grdEmpDetail_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = -1;
        this.grdEmpDetail.DataBind();
    }
```

OUTPUT: This is fine

[image]

ISSUE : This is where I am getting issue.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you post the entire `Page_Load` handler?  Are you checking for `IsPostBack` in your databinding code?

Comment: @MikeC I've update it. I am not checking `IsPostBack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking for `IsPostBack` in your databinding code.  As a result, each time you post to the page that code is being executed again and again.  So each time you will add more columns.

<s>Modify your handler like so:</s>

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack) {
       // All of your existing code goes here
    }
}
```

**Edit**

It's a little more complicated than that.  You DO actually need to re-bind your DataGrid to the data source when you click edit, but you just don't want to add the columns again.  This requires that you break up your code some so that the code for data-binding can be re-used without being tied to the column addition.

First, let's create a method specifically for adding columns that appear on an input `DataTable`:

```
private void AddColumnsToDataGrid(DataTable dt) {

    foreach (var col in dt.Columns) {
        if (col.ToString() == "ID" 
            || col.ToString() == "First Name" 
            || col.ToString() == "Last Name" 
            || col.ToString() == "Business Phone" 
            || col.ToString() == "Job Title")
        {
            BoundField objBoundField = new BoundField();
            objBoundField.DataField = col.ToString();
            objBoundField.HeaderText = col.ToString();
            this.grdEmpDetail.Columns.Add(objBoundField);
        }
    }

}
```

Next Create a Method for Databinding a `DataTable` to your grid:

```
private void DataBindGrid(DataTable dt) {

    this.grdEmpDetail.DataSource = dt;
    this.grdEmpDetail.DataBind();

}
```

Now that you've extracted some of that code out, you can re-use these methods where appropriate, and only add columns one time:

**Page Load Handler**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack) {

        WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject objBL = new WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject();
        this.grdEmpDetail.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        try {
            DataTable dt = objBL.OrderDetail();
            AddColumnsToDataGrid(dt);
            DataBindGrid(dt);
        } catch {
            // Side Note:  If you're just re-throwing the exception
            // then the try/catch block is completely useless.
            throw;
        }

    }

}
```

**Editing Handlers**

```
protected void grdEmpDetail_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject objBL = new WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject();    
    DataBindGrid(objBL.OrderDetail());

}

protected void grdEmpDetail_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = -1;

    WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject objBL = new WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject();    
    DataBindGrid(objBL.OrderDetail());

}
```

Comment: in that case grid becomes empty even though I am binding the grid(in `_RowEditing` method) . Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, do not call `DataBind` again.

Comment: I see but now I have to click twice on `Edit` and `Cancel`. On First click it is not doing anything.

Comment: I was wrong about not calling DataBind again, but your code will need to be refactored some in order to only do certain things at certain times.  I've updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Fill_Grid();
    }
}
protected Void Fill_Grid()
{

    if (grdEmpDetail.Columns.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < grdEmpDetail.Columns.Count; n++)
        {
            grdEmpDetail.Columns.RemoveAt(n);

        }
     grdEmpDetail.DataBind();
    }
    this.grdEmpDetail.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject objBL = new WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject();
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = objBL.OrderDetail();
        foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ToString() == "ID" || col.ToString() == "First Name" || col.ToString() == "Last Name" || col.ToString() == "Business Phone" || col.ToString() == "Job Title")
            {
                BoundField objBoundField = new BoundField();
                objBoundField.DataField = col.ToString();
                objBoundField.HeaderText = col.ToString();
                this.grdEmpDetail.Columns.Add(objBoundField);
            }
        }
        this.grdEmpDetail.DataSource = dt;
        this.grdEmpDetail.DataBind();
    }
    catch (exception e1)
    {
    }
}
protected void grdEmpDetail_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    Fill_Grid();
}

protected void grdEmpDetail_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = -1;
    Fill_Grid();
}
```

Comment: Simply moving the data-binding code to a separate method is functionally no different from the original problem.  You have to separate the data-binding from the addition of columns like in my updated example.

Comment: yes, need to remove all columns in Fill_Grid(), btw thanks @MikeC

Comment: I agree with `Mike C` as I tried that approach and basically it is doing the same thing.